# Nodejs request - CAS authentication scraping

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cas

I'm trying to scrape a website which is using CAS for authentication.

I am currently running node.js `request` library to make requests and `cheerio` for body parsing. Schema of my app looks like this:

**1. Go to CAS auth login page at login.XXX.com**

I scrape hidden fields to make my POST request look exactly like I did it in my browser. Create cookie jar. Ok.

**2. Log in - POST request.**

I send all the data, using the same cookie jar, and followAllRedirects enabled. I can see that I am logged in successfuly, as I get correct message. Also, cookies `CASUSERNAME` and `CASTGC` are saved into cookie jar.

**3. Try to go to service at service.XXX.com**

I make a simple GET request to the service, using my cookie jar... and... I am not logged in. I can't really see if there have been any XHR requests done on the way, I don't really know how to check it or what to do to make myself authenticated.

Any ideas how to get to the service after logging in would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

**Where was the issue:**

When my script was trying to enter the service (service.XXX.com), the service site sended a XHR request to CAS login server (at login.XXX.com) and tried to redirect back to requested service, which somehow caused my app to go into infinite redirects loop.

**Solution:**

I had to go request after request, and carefully, manually redirect (make GET requests) to the site in headers (`headers.location`). The XHR request created PHPSESSID on it's way, so I just had to save it inside my cookie jar and then continue to use the service sites I wanted.

Hope it helps someone.